# Application migrations calling service layer

Tags: database, migration, release, database-migration, continuous-deployment

Typically, when it comes to migrations, we refer to **database migrations**, and most tools are designed around this idea. With such approach, the migration contains only SQL code which directly changes database schema and possibly data.

However, when it comes to complex enterprise applications, sometimes SQL is not enough to migrate application from previous version to a new one.

Consider an example where each user in the application has a rating and it was calculated by using *algorithm A* in previous versions of the application, but now, should be calculated by a newer *algorithm B*. So, in order to migrate from old version of the app to the new one, we have to call service layer in order to re-calculate the rating for each user (which is not possible to do solely by SQL, because it requires a more complex logic, contained in the service layer of the application). Considering, this is the only change between versions, we doesn't even need to change schema or run any SQL directly.

SO, how do you handle such **application migrations**? What is the standard approach in the industry to release new versions of the application in automatic and determined way?

As I've mentioned, the current migration tools are not very well suited to run any complex code besides SQL. I was thinking about creating a custom tool, which will be able to both handle SQL queries and calls to a service layer of the application from migrations. Is this a good approach?

If so, should I design this tool to be integrated to the application context and be able to freely call any service internally, or should I expose some commands from my application and run them by external requests from the migration (e.g. via shell)?

I want my app to fully support continuous deployment with automatic migrations.

Answer (score 0):

*I will try to provide here results of my own research and best practices I will try to come up with regarding the matter. I will periodically update this answer, but feel free to add your own answers and/or comments.*

---

## Interesting/related articles:

- https://kostasbariotis.com/data-migration-with-nodejs/